# async/wait confusing code in Angular - the order is wrong

Tags: angular, asynchronous, promise, async-await

```
async getRequest(node_id, uri, params) {
    var children_nodes = [];
    const request_response: any = await this.http.get(uri, {params: params}).toPromise();
    request_response.children.forEach(element => {
      children_nodes.push({'node_id': element.node_id});
    });
    return children_nodes;
}

async myMainFunction(node_ids) {
    let fetch_all_node_ids = async () => {
      var children_nodes = [];
      node_ids.forEach(node_id => {
        var uri = some_url;
        var param = some_params;
        console.log('calling this.getRequest');
        this.getRequest(node_id, uri, param).then((children_nodes: any) => {
            children_nodes.forEach(node_dict => {
              console.log('pushing into children_nodes:', node_dict);
              children_nodes.push(node_dict);
            })
        });
      });
      return children_nodes;
    };
    const children_nodes = await fetch_all_node_ids();
    console.log('before finishing myMainFunction: ', children_nodes);
    return children_nodes;
}
```

I am new to Angular and I am stuck here:

why am I getting in my console first

`before finishing myMainFunction: ...`

and then:

`pushing into children_nodes:` ?

I want to return the array only once it is filled with responses of get request inside the loop. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`forEach` does not wait for each loop to execute async code and also your promise inside the loop also does not make the loop wait either.

A `for of` loop will wait for async functions correctly if you await them rather than use the `.then` promise format:

```
async myMainFunction(node_ids) {
    let fetch_all_node_ids = async () => {
      var children_nodes = [];
      for (const node_id of node_ids) {
        var uri = some_url;
        var param = some_params;
        console.log('calling this.getRequest');
        const children_nodes = await this.getRequest(node_id, uri, param)
        children_nodes.forEach(node_dict => {
          console.log('pushing into children_nodes:', node_dict);
          children_nodes.push(node_dict);
        })
      }
      return children_nodes;
    };
    const children_nodes = await fetch_all_node_ids();
    console.log('before finishing myMainFunction: ', children_nodes);
    return children_nodes;
}
```

Comment: why is that forEach does not wait for async and for of will wait for async ?

Comment: @SatishPai because the implementation of forEach is just a for loop but it doesn't await the callback